# Is Doctrine Really That Slow (30times slower than PDO)?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've been using Doctrine with Symfony for a while now and annoyed by how slow it is. I started looking into it a bit more and can't believe the speed differences.

I simple sql query run directly in PDO would take about **5ms**

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE id=1
```

The same query in Doctrine with hydration into an Object takes around **150ms**. That's 30times slower.

```
$em = Application::getDoctrineEntityManager();
$event = $em->find(Event::class, 1);
```

My event object isn't even very large and I've set all relationships to  fetch="EXTRA_LAZY" so there shouldn't be any problem with any extra work or extra queries.

Am I missing something? Clearly an extra 145ms for writing data from the database result into an object is unacceptably long.

Comment: How would that work ? I'm following Doctrine's tutorial (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.10/tutorials/getting-started.html) which suggests using the EntityManager

Comment: @YoussefSaoubou I appreciate your humor but I suspect the OP might be taking you seriously.

Comment: I deleted my comments

Comment: Please show us how exactly you measure the execution time. I assume that 150ms is taken by the infrastructure initialization (e.g. during the first query). You can try to run 2 queries `($event2 = $em->find(Event::class, 2);` and check whether the time doubled

Comment: The time only increases by a few ms when I add a second event query. So that indicates that the infrastructure initialization takes that long? But then, why does it only takes 5ms when I change AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_OBJECT into AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY ? That still uses the same infrastructure (EntityManager and the Event Repository)

Comment: Object hydration uses reflection to directly transfer array data to the object's properties.  As well as a bit extra to support lazy loading when applicable.  So there is overhead.  But I am a bit skeptical that it takes as long your timing checks seem to indicate.  There is also a question of how long it takes to hydrate vs how long the complete request/response processing takes.  In most cases you probably won't notice a significant difference between using the ORM and using PDO at the application level.  But there are always exceptions.